# Background image 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sempre tive essa curiosidade, de como deixar a imagem de background 100% de acordo com o monitor ( Todos nós sabemos que existem diversas medidas). Então me disseram que seria um script em JS ou jQuery, não me lembro muito bem, e ele funcionava da seguinte forma:

Você cria diversas imagens com as seguintes medidas:

```
1024x768-
1280x768-
1360x768-
1366x768-
```

São resoluções do meu notebook, pode ser que tenham outras medidas.

Quando você acessa o site, esse script faz a leitura da medida e carrega tal imagem. 
é dessa forma mesmo que funciona? Teria a possibilidade de fazer isso no CSS?

Exemplo em um site : http://www.adobe.com/br/products/dreamweaver.html

Comment: background image 100% tu não precisa de js, é só por width e height 100%. Mas sobre o que falou de adaptação de acordo com a resolução, pode usar media queries...

Answer (score 5):

<sup>Existem diversas técnicas para obter uma imagem a ocupar toda a largura e altura do ecrã. Cada técnica é considerada adequada para determinado cenário pois podemos lidar com o problema via JavaScript, CSS ou no lado do servidor.</sup>

<sup>Nesta resposta as soluções fazem uso de JavaScript com recurso a jQuery.</sup>

## jQuery

#### [Imagem consoante largura do ecrã](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Este Plugin funciona da forma que tu indicas na pergunta, ou seja, ele faz uso de diversas imagens carregando a mais adequada consoante a largura do ecrã:

```
(function() {

var win = $(window);

win.resize(function() {

    var win_w = win.width(),
        win_h = win.height(),
        $bg    = $("#bg");

    // Carregar imagem de fundo mais estreita com base na
    // largura do ecrã, mas nunca carregar nada mais estreito
    // do que o que já está carregado, se alguma coisa estiver.
    var available = [
      1024, 1280, 1366,
      1400, 1680, 1920,
      2560, 3840, 4860
    ];

    var current = $bg.attr('src').match(/([0-9]+)/) ? RegExp.$1 : null;

    if (!current || ((current < win_w) && (current < available[available.length - 1]))) {

      var chosen = available[available.length - 1];

      for (var i=0; i<available.length; i++) {
        if (available[i] >= win_w) {
          chosen = available[i];
          break;
        }
      }

      // Definir a nova imagem
      $bg.attr('src', '/img/bg/' + chosen + '.jpg');

      // para testar...
      // console.log('Chosen background: ' + chosen);

    }

    // Determinar se a largura ou a altura deve ser de 100%
    if ((win_w / win_h) < ($bg.width() / $bg.height())) {
      $bg.css({height: '100%', width: 'auto'});
    } else {
      $bg.css({width: '100%', height: 'auto'});
    }

  }).resize();

})(jQuery);
```

Código retirado do web site CSS-Tricks neste artigo:

[Perfect Full Page Background Image | CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

---

#### [Vegas Background jQuery Plugin](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/)

Muito fácil de utilizar, permite-nos transformar uma simples `<img/>` numa imagem a ocupar 100% X 100% do ecrã, bem como indicar a imagem no próprio *PlugIn*:

1. Incluir o *Script* após a inclusão do *jQuery*:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/vegas/jquery.vegas.js"></script>
   ```
2. Incluir o *CSS*:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vegas/jquery.vegas.css" />
   ```
3. Iniciar o *PlugIn*:

   ```
   $(function() {
     $.vegas({
       src:'/images/background.jpg'
     });
   });
   ```

   [Vegas - Demonstração](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/)

Answer (score 4):

Podes fazer isso com CSS da seguinte maneira: http://jsfiddle.net/ez7eq1Lm/

```css
#banner{
    background:url('https://dq197.infusionsoft.com/Download?Id=2300') no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    width:100%;
    height:260px;
}
```

O valor [`contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Values) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> na propriedade `background-size` permite:

> Esta palavra-chave especifica que a imagem de fundo deve ser dimensionada para ser tão grande quanto possível, assegurando ao mesmo tempo que as suas dimensões são menores ou iguais às dimensões correspondentes da zona de posicionamento do fundo.

Answer (score 3):

Dá pra fazer pelo CSS assim:

```
body {
    background: url(caminho_para_a_imagem);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**cover:** Redimenciona a imagem para preencher completamente a area do background, mantendo a proporção.

Caso não se importe com a proporção, você pode usar:

```
body {
    background: url(caminho_para_a_imagem);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Existem [outros parâmetros](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover), escolha o que atende melhor as suas necessidades.